# efficient string hash strategy for network json ID

Tags: json, algorithm, hash

Currently my json key string have average length of 9 bytes, if I can use some avaliable algorithm to make it an unsigned long(32 bit, 4 bytes) as the new ID, which can save lots of bandwidth between client and server.  That is:

before: {"player_vip_type": 'xxxx', 'player_gold_coin_count':500, 'some_other_stuff':500}

after: {0xAFDE0901:'xxxx', 0xAEEDED02:500, 0x0030FAD3:500}

I have study and test some of string hash strategy mentioned in [Which hashing algorithm is best for uniqueness and speed?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed). if the string set is big enough , we just can't prevent key conflict. I know some strategy for repair key conflict, but it won't work as json ID both in client and server.

So is there any method to do this server-client hash json key ID?

As my first thought, is there a algorithm like this:

1) if one string hash result does't exist, make it a uint_32 ID , using a effective uint_32 hash algorithm(the reuslt ID should > oxFFFF), this called bigger ID

2) if one string hash result already exist, make the exsit and new one a uint_16 ID, using a different effective uint_16 algorithm(the result ID should <= 0xFFFF) ,this called smaller ID

3) when getting a string id, first use getBiggerId (ID > oxFFFF), if not exist then use getSmallerID(ID <= oxFFFF)

does this algorithm feasible and how to realize it ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't. It is very likely that under the hood, some compression will be involved while transferring data from server to client, and anything you try to do only interferes with it.

Here's an idea that actually saves memory: Instead of an array with hundred dictionaries, each with keys player_vip_type, player_gold_coin_count and some_other_stuff, send one dictionary with these three keys, and each having an array with hundred strings or numbers as the value.